# Change WooCommerce Subscription Product Start Date Before Adding to Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

One of my WooCommerce websites that uses WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin has a problem.

The problem is one product is only shipped every 2 weeks on a certain date.

The next shipping date is November 9th.

I need to figure out how to add this as the default start date for the product.

I tried using the features described in the WC_Subscriptions_Synchroniser class of the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin.

I enabled the Synchronise Renewals feature.

[image]

And also changed the Synchronise Renewals date to Friday of each week as November 9th is a Friday.

[image]

However, this makes the First renewal date be November 2nd which is the upcoming Friday.

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to delay the start date to November 9th instead of the November 2nd it is displaying now.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same issue here. 
I managed to prepare a future start date, but there is a hard coded limitation to this.

Check out this piece of code in wcs_function.php

```
// validate the start_date field
if ( ! is_string( $args['start_date'] ) || false === wcs_is_datetime_mysql_format( $args['start_date'] ) ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'woocommerce_subscription_invalid_start_date_format', _x( 'Invalid date. The date must be a string and of the format: "Y-m-d H:i:s".', 'Error message while creating a subscription', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ) );
} else if ( wcs_date_to_time( $args['start_date'] ) > current_time( 'timestamp', true ) ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'woocommerce_subscription_invalid_start_date', _x( 'Subscription start date must be before current day.', 'Error message while creating a subscription', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ) );
}
```

**It is not possible to create a subscription in the future.** This is maybe related to Subscription plugin limitation, or a very narrow approach to the subscription problem.

Meaning that even juggling with cart item properties through `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data`, `wcs_recurring_cart_start_date`, `woocommerce_get_item_data` as I did you'll be eventually hitting a wall. **You'll either need to alter Woocommerce Subscription hard limits or be very creative.**

Now, i'll show you my 3 action/filters involved, that's rather simple. I've simplified the stuff because it involved date validation and formatting that you may not need.

You'll need a `my_delay_post_attr` POST field in your product page.

First save into the cart item some custom field you added on the product page.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'my_woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 10, 1);
/**
 * Read a Y-m-d H:i:s formatted (mysql) date from POST data
 * then store it in the cart item.
 * @param $cart_item_data array
 */
function my_woocommerce_add_cart_item_data($cart_item_data)
{
    if (@$_POST['my_delay_post_attr']) {
        $cart_item_data['my_delay_post_attr'] = $_POST['my_delay_post_attr'];
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Now, let's alter start date upon CART -> ORDER step:

```
add_filter('wcs_recurring_cart_start_date', 'my_wcs_recurring_cart_start_date', 10, 2);
/**
 * @param string $date
 * @param \WC_Cart $recurring_cart
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function my_wcs_recurring_cart_start_date($date, $recurring_cart) {
    $cartContents = $recurring_cart->cart_contents;

    if (!$cartContents) {
        return $date;
    }

    if (!count($cartContents)) {
        return $date;
    }

    $key = array_keys($cartContents)[0];

    // I'd suggest you not to trust this, and apply some verification here
    return @$cartContents[$key]['my_delay_post_attr];
}
```

And finally display this information in cart page:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'my_woocommerce_get_item_data', 10, 2 );

public static function my_woocommerce_get_item_data( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if (!@$cart_item['my_delay_post_attr']) {
        return $item_data;
    }

    $item_data[] = array(
        'key'     => 'Start of the subscription',
        'value'   => $cart_item['my_delay_post_attr'],
        'display' => '',
    );

    return $item_data;
}
```

EDIT: 
I've reached Prosspress support and this is what they answered me about this hard limit on future subscriptions:

> I understand you're trying to manually create a subscription and are
>   asking about the limitation around the start date needing to be in the
>   future.  This limitation is there to support the gateways, as some are
>   very specific and rigid around the timing of subscriptions. You may
>   be safe to create a workaround for that check, but we can't make any
>   promises - the check is there for a reason.
>   If you are insistent on
>   removing it, please run thorough testing on a development environment
>   first to ensure there are no issues with your gateway.

EDIT2:

I can confirm that PAYPAL won't work with this trick. As for Prosspress response:

> We are unsure how Stripe and Mercanet would handle this change. (We do
>   know for sure that PayPal Standard, for example, would not handle this
>   well.)
>
> If you decide to move forward with this, we recommend testing very
>   thoroughly. However, I wonder if there is a more simple option to
>   accomplish what you are trying to achieve? Do you need the actual
>   creation date to be in the future, or do you just need the first
>   payment to be in the future?
>
> If the latter, rather than trying to change date_created, you might
>   consider using a free trial or creating a false free trial. This is
>   the functionality used for subscription synchronization. Also, we
>   recently separated out date_created and start_date in the database.
>   While this functionality isn't fully developed yet, it might give you
>   another point to work with as you move forward with your
>   customization.

Comment: bravo, this is exceptional stuff, much apprecaited

Comment: @JackRobson i've managed to reach the support about this issue, and you'll find their answer about my fix. I hope it can help you. :)

Comment: I have a an idea, tell me this can be work or not.  I have 1st day of every month renewal subscription item. when customer want to start as example 10th of December (2019-12-10). I will calculate line total from 10 to 31st. by default it will calculate from today to 30st November. But now i manually calculate 10st of Dec to 31st of December. Then my next payment set to 1st of January. by default this would be 1st of December. 
Any suggestions and ideas ?